# Resource id cannot be an empty string(at 'id' with value '@+id/")

Tags: android, android-activity

When trying to run an android activity I get this error:
Error:(8, 17) Resource id cannot be an empty string (at 'id' with value '@+id/').
It seems to be an error with only the last activity. Every time I try to run the program, a line is added to the end of the activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainMenu">
```

Becomes

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.kirky_000.madmath.Multiplication"
    android:id="@+id/">
```

and the error is only with the "android:id="@+id/">".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give an id to the relativeLayout, just don't leave it empty. It can be anything you want. For example: `android:id="@+id/myRelativeLayout"` . Your RelativeLayout would look something like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.kirky_000.madmath.Multiplication"
android:id="@+id/myRelativeLayout">
```